# Subdomains with Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask

How might I go about implementing subdomains for my website with Flask?

The documentation, though very good, isn't very clear at all about this. 
The subdomains need not to be dynamic, I am only going to be using 2 or 3 of my own choosing.

How would I route them? Is it possible to test them in the normal way? (served locally by Flask)

Comment: Flask doesn't care about the hostname so much; it's domain is the path *following* the hostname; what would you need to do with each hostname?

Comment: Just have a couple of subdomains like blog.mywebsite.com, etc. Thats why I was confused, since when you set up routing for applications you only specify the path after the domain name.

Comment: It's up to how you set up the WSGI server to handle certain domain names. Virtual Servers in Apache, for example.

Comment: That *can* be the same Flask application, but then you'd have to add additional handling of the specific domain name to match routes.

Comment: I'm still lost, this is what I was looking at - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/, but it seems to be overly complicated for what I want to implement

Comment: That is a WSGI-server-level approach too, albeit implemented by WSGI middleware. Flask, wrapped in the middleware layer, doesn't (need to) know that it is contained in a middleware object instead of a WSGI server there.

Comment: @user3233758: Please realize that different people have different ideas for what they mean by "implementing subdomains". On the one hand, you might have multiple subdomains all point to different Flask apps. In another, multiple subdomains point to a single Flask app, and that Flask app does something different depending on which domain the request was sent to. Can you be more specific in terms of telling us what you want to do?

Answer (score 21):

If all you want to do is handle having particular endpoints under a particular subdomain, you can just [use the `subdomain`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations) argument to `@route`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# In Flask 1.0
# app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)

# Must add this until Flask 1.0
# Must be host:port pair or will not work
app.config["SERVER_NAME"] = "local.dev:5000"

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Sweet home"

@app.route("/some-route")
def some_route():
    return "on the default subdomain (generally, www, or unguarded)"

@app.route("/", subdomain="blog")
def blog_home():
    return "Sweet blog"

@app.route("/<page>", subdomain="blog")
def blog_page(page):
    return "can be dynamic: {}".format(page)
```

To handle development locally, you need to create entries in your `hosts` file to point these various domains to your machine:

```
local.dev    127.0.0.1
blog.local.dev    127.0.0.1
```

Then you can use `local.dev` and `blog.local.dev` rather than `localhost` to see your work.

Comment: This is not working on my computer. Both local.dev and blog.local.dev returns "sweet home"??!!

Comment: @AliKhosro - I'd left out a crucial detail (setting `SERVER_NAME`).  That's been fixed now and it *should* work.

Comment: how to do this with class based views?

Comment: I would advise against editing `hosts` and instead use free services like https://readme.localtest.me/ With modified `hosts` dev environment was messy and not fully functional before. `SERVER_NAME=localtest.me` was smooth sailing in local subdomain testing